# Using orderBy() with getAll();

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am a newbie and I have this code where I am trying to sort my categories by alpabetically, could you please help me how to do this by using OrderBy on my code?

```
                foreach ($categoryList as $index => $category) {

                    $categories[$index]['category'] = $category;
                    $categories[$index]['sub'] = DB::table('category')->where('mainID','=',$category->id)->getAll();

            }
```

Many thanks.

**

> I have fixed my issue by replacing my code to this;

**

```
        public function all(){

            $categories = array();

            $categoryList = DB::table('category as table1')
                                            ->where('table1.mainID','=',0)
                                            ->orderBy('table1.id','DESC')
                                            ->getAll();

            foreach ($categoryList as $index => $category) {

                    $categories[$index]['category'] = $category;
                    $categories[$index]['sub'] = DB::table('category')->orderBy('category.name','ASC')->where('mainID','=',$category->id)->getAll();

            }

            return (object) $categories;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `orderBy` before the `getAll`?

Comment: I am really new at this and everytime I have tried to do that my website has crashed. I am probably adding it wrong that is why I have copied my code hoping that someone would copy me back the edited version of it.